# JSF 2.2 Display HTML based on condition

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jstl

When this is true

```
#{loginController.authenticated}
```

I want to display this:

```
<li><a href="#{request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a></li>
```

else i want to display this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#{request.contextPath}/login">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#{request.contextPath}/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
```

Is the best way to do that using JSTL c:choose/when statements in jsf 2.2 or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  around you li items and use the `rendered` attribute to display the fragment conditionally.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{loginController.authenticated}">
    <li><a href="#{request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a></li>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{!loginController.authenticated}">
    <li class="active"><a href="#{request.contextPath}/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#{request.contextPath}/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
</ui:fragment>
```